# Save data in Magento from outside

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, mysql

I have created one module in magento 1.9. There is a requirement to save data from outside the root folder. Can any one help me in solving this. I have connected this using the following code.

```
include 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
<?php
    $mageFilename = 'path/to/root/app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin');
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    /*
     * Your code here
     */
```